# How to get index number across multiple lists in XSL 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to transform an xml table with XSL 1.0. The table has two blocks `thead` and `tbody`, which both have 0...n `row`. Rows have entries (aka cells).

```
<Table>
  <Tgroup cols="6">
    <Thead>
      <Row>
        <Entry> this is row 1 </Entry>
        <Entry> this is row 1</Entry>
      </Row>
    </Thead>
    <Tbody>
      <Row>
        <Entry> this is row 2 </Entry>
        <Entry> this is row 2 </Entry>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Entry> this is row 3 </Entry>
        <Entry> this is row 3 </Entry>
      </Row>
    </Tbody>
  </Tgroup>
</Table>
```

How can I get the row index (when transforming `entry`) over both `tbody` and `thead`?
When I count rows in tbody, it ignores the rows thead. Unfortunately, I have to count those too, if there are any.

Here is my current template, which does not do what I want:

```
<xsl:template match="Entry">
  <!-- only counts inside the same ancestor, e.g. only rows in tbody -->
  <xsl:number count="../../*[name()='Row']" from="*[self::*[name()='Tgroup']]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(Yes I know that `name()='Row'` is not good, but the original xsl uses variables for the node names.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
 <xsl:number count="*[name()='Row']" level="any"/>
```

Or maybe this, if your XML actually has namespaces (as I don't understand what you mean by saying your XSL uses variables for the node names)

```
 <xsl:number count="*[local-name()='Row']" level="any"/>
```

The difference being that the latter would work in the case where you had a namespace prefix, like `<my:Row>`

EDIT: In response to your comment, try using the `from` attribute

```
<xsl:number count="*[local-name()='Row']" level="any" from="Table"/>
```

Comment: It does not have namespaces, the name()='' pattern is used with variables: `*[name()=$row]`. But it's not important, sorry for the confusion!
That solution works as long as there is only a single table per xml document. Unfortunately, I can have multiple tables, so the counter has to be "local" to `table`.

Comment: Ah! I see. It would still be best to use `local-name()` in this case, as this would work if you did have namespaces in the future (so it would match `my:row`, whereas `name()` wouldn't). In any case, I have amended my answer to show you have can cope with multiple `Table` nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, I fought with xsl:number for hours, but the spec and the examples only confused me - that thing is really counter-intuitive (at least to me). And of course, local-name is the better choice.